# Selected columns names are not displayed properly

Tags: sql, subquery

I don't know why, when run my query, the word "select" is displayed with the name of column, what is wrong with my code?

```
select
  PRENOM_UTI ||' '|| NOM_UTI as NOM_UTILISATEUR,
  TEL_UTI, 
  COURRIEL_UTI,
  (select TYPE_UTI from UTILISATEUR where TYPE_UTI in 'Invite'),
  (select NOM_ORG from ORGANISME where NOM_ORG in ('ABC'))
from UTILISATEUR;
```

[image]

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  It should be generating an error.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify alias name for 4th & 5th field

```
select
  PRENOM_UTI ||' '|| NOM_UTI as NOM_UTILISATEUR,
  TEL_UTI, 
  COURRIEL_UTI,
  (select TYPE_UTI from UTILISATEUR where TYPE_UTI in 'Invite') Alias1,
  (select NOM_ORG from ORGANISME where NOM_ORG in ('ABC')) Alias2
from UTILISATEUR;
```